# Return post data angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post

Im trying to receive data posted by Angular:

```
$scope.add = function() {
        $http.post($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test', {"data": "fiskapa"})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            //Göra något
        });
    };
```

The problem is that fiskapa is not returned:

```
public function create($data)
    {
        return new JsonModel(array("data" => $data));
    }
```

Data that is returned:  Object { data=[0]}

Comment: What is your backend framework ?

Comment: Im using Zend Framework. How can I get the post data then?

Comment: You can't access POST params in the same way like GET params. With **Zend** it's with `$this->getRequest()->getPost('data', null);`

Comment: How can I access the POST-params and it'data?

Comment: The problem is not angular. Your API service is returning an array just like the on that you are showing. Is [0] and empty array? or an array that contains an element 0?

Do you have a way to debug your code and get information of what is the value of $data before returning it?

Comment: @htellez: The $data is just an empty variable.

Comment: I don't know how to use it my example?

Comment: In your example : `$datas = $this->getRequest()->getPost('data'); // Get fiskapa` and your param is in the `$datas` var

Comment: Im trying this: $datas=$this->getRequest()->getPost('data');
return new JsonModel(array("data" => $datas)); but that just give me:  Object { data=null}

Answer (score 0):

You can get directly the json post:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
```

Please, try this.